# Draw text on canvas and make it visible on screen

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

This code was supposed to convert text to image

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setTextSize(16);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);

        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(16, 16, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
        float x = bm.getWidth();
        float y = bm.getHeight();
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
        c.drawText("Test", x, y, paint);
}
```

Is this code ok? If yes, how can I make this new bitmap visible on screen? I tried this code which produced an error

```
setContentView(c); //<- ERROR!
```

I am confused with the element `Canvas` as there is not such element in XML which I can use in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setContentView(View)` takes a `View` and [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) is not a `View`.

I am not sure that you want to create a `Canvas` on your own.  There are ways to get a `Canvas` passed to you from the Android Framework though.  One way you can do this is by creating a custom `View`.  To do this, you will need to create a new class that extends `View`.

When overriding a `View` class, you will have the ability to override the `onDraw(Canvas)` method.  This is probably where you want to do what you are attempting to do in your `onCreate()` method in the code you posted.

[This link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) gives a good overview of what is required to create your own custom view.

Answer (score 2):

First: If you draw your text at the x and y position you specified, you draw it
at the lower right corner, starting with exactly that pixel. Nothing will be drawn on your canvas. Try bm.getWidth()/2, for height the same for test drawing. You can optimize that later.

Second: Canvas is not a View (does not extend the View class). You can only set Views via set ContentView(). What I recommend here is writing a XML layout containing only a single ImageView  and set that via setContentView(R.layout.mylayout).

After that, you can use findViewById() to grab that ImageView and use ImageView.setImageBitmap(bm) to show your bitmap on it.
You dont have to do anything with the canvas, once you created it with your bitmap. Everything  you draw inside the canvas from that point on is found in the Bitmap immediately.
Therefore you can't specify the Canvas in XML. It's just an "Editor" to edit pictures, so to speak and not an actual UI element.

Comment: Your post was very helpful as well, but nicholas pointed out more points that led me to the solution. Thanks once more again.